# Need help with Google drive API

Tags: php, post-meta, uploads

I am currently working on a WordPress website which has almost the same functionality as YouTube(log in, upload videos, create channels etc..).
My requirement is,

**When a new user is logged in and uploads a video(from an HTML form), then the video has to be saved in the admin's google drive account. Then the URL or embedded code of that uploaded video has to save in the site's backend as a post meta data.**

How can I accomplish this using google drive api?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** The upload video form is a simple HTML form that contains a file upload field for video and a submit button. I'm currently saving these details as a blog post and the video is uploaded to the media library.

Comment: Have you considered using plugins such as [WP Offload](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/)?

Comment: Hi, the thing is that I don't need the currently uploading file to go to WordPress media library.It has to directly go to the google drive from the form. After that, the shared link/embedded code from that video has to be saved in the WordPress site as post meta.

Comment: I understand. And the linked plugin will be able to do that for you. By default, it will upload all media to your external resource, so a) you use it that way or b) need some tweaking, maybe look into the Pro version or get in touch with the developers if this is possible.

Comment: I did it. The question is marked as closed, so I can't post the answer.